# Which is the truth percentage of the test?

Tags: probability, statistics, percentages

We suppose that $10\%$ of population has been diagnosed by a virus according to a test. Among them $60\%$ has indeed the virus (the test is correct) but among them who has not been diagnosed the percentage that they have been diagnosed is $20\%$ (the test is wrong).

Which is the truth percentage of the test?

We have to use here the conditional probability, or not?

Do we have to calculate $P(\text{truly diagnosed}\mid \text{diagnosed by test})$ ?

Comment: Assume there are $1000$ people. Now make a table, where you have four regions: positive/negative (test result), and healthy/sick.

Comment: Any resemblance to real and actual virus  is purely coincidental.

Answer (score 1):

Assume there are $1000$ people in total. Now set up the following table:
$$\begin{array} {c|c|c} & \text{Positive test} & \text{Negative test} \\ \hline
\text{Sick} & &  \\ \hline \text{Healthy} & & \\ \end{array}$$

Therefore, there are $100$ people who test positive. $60$ of them have the virus, and $40$ of them do not.

Now fill in the remaining boxes in the same way. You should get:

$$\begin{array} {c|c|c} & \text{Positive test} & \text{Negative test} \\ \hline
\text{Sick} & 60 & 180 \\ \hline \text{Healthy} & 40 & 720 \\ \end{array}$$

and from here you can find the accuracy rate of the test.

Comment: Ah ok! I got it with the table! But which is the accuracy rate? Is it maybe $$P((\text{Positive}\cap \text{Sick})\cup (\text{Negative}\cap \text{Healthy})$$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: It is $P(\text{Positive}\cap \text{Sick})+P(\text{Negative}\cap \text{Healthy})-P[(\text{Positive}\cap \text{Sick})\cap (\text{Negative}\cap \text{Healthy})]$ right?

Comment: We have that $P(\text{Positive}\cap \text{Sick})=\frac{60}{1000}$, $P(\text{Negative}\cap \text{Healthy})=\frac{720}{1000}$, correct so far? But what is $P[(\text{Positive}\cap \text{Sick})\cap (\text{Negative}\cap \text{Healthy})]$ ?

Comment: It's just $\frac{60}{1000} + \frac{720}{1000}$.

Comment: Ah because the last intersection is zero, right?

Comment: Note that on this basis, a test which always said "Negative" would be almost as accurate ($76\%$ rather than $78\%$) even though it would be useless